# Install of local python library created using nbdev cannot be found

Tags: python, pip, nbdev

I am creating a [library](https://github.com/JonnoB/pyseatrials) using nbdev. Following the instructions [here](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html).

My file structure is the same as given in the instructions, with the library installed at top level of the repo and the notebooks in the 'nbs' folder

```
repo folder
|_ settings.ini
|_ setup.py
|_ nbs
|_ library folder
|_ etc
```

After creating the library. You are supposed to install the library using `pip install -e .`. When I do this I see the dependencies checks passing and get a message saying installation is successful.

However, when I open a notebook inside the `nbs` folder and try and import the library using

```
from pyseatrials.trig import *
```

I get the error message  `No module named 'pyseatrials'`

However, if I create a new notebook in the top level of the repo the import is sucessful. The same occurs if I use the terminal

```
python3
from seatrials import *
```

However any other directory produces the 'not found' error. In addition the library does not show up on `pip list`

This this is not the behaviour I was expecting after reading the instructions or watching the introduction video.

I am using

- pip 22.3
- python 3.9
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

How do I fix the import issue and what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around the issue by installing direct from git using

```
python -m pip install git+<URL to library repo>
```

It isn't the best approach but it does work